# DNN manifest - module category

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is it possible to set the module category in a DNN manifest file so a package containing lots of related modules can be categorised? It doesn't have to add the the taxonomy, an existing entry is fine.

The DNN Wiki seems to suggest not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently with DNN. You can only set the Category by editing the module via the extensions page AFTER installing a module.